# Is there any security risk from my kids knowing their minecraft password?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I created a Minecraft account for my kids, I had to create an account on Mojang and buy a Minecraft account using a credit card.

As my kids use the Mojang account details to sign in to Minecraft, I've been reluctant to allow them to know the password.  But they need to keep signing in as it times out the login credentials from time to time and it would be more convenient if they knew their own password.

Are there any security implications from them knowing their own Minecraft passwords?  My primary concern is the fact that I used my credit card to buy the original account, but also there may be other implications given that once the kids know them, I don't have the same level of security over the passwords as when only I know them.

Answer (score 20):

Minecraft does not save credit card details, so there is no risk of your kids spending all your money on merchandise or buying more copies of Minecraft.

The only risk I can think of would be if they gave the password to their friends and lost the account that way, but you're the parent here so it's up to you how you stop them doing that.

Comment: Losing the account is a fairly big risk, in this context, I wouldn't downplay it so much.

Comment: If they give out the password they kind of deserve it. It'll be a good lesson for them to be careful with passwords ;)

Comment: Don't buy the account for them again.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no security risk. In fact, Mojang doesn't save credit card data. Once you bought a copy, it won't store it and/or ever use it again.

But to answer your question, no, there is no 'big' security risk.

Comment: **This would make your kids more responsible and at the moment that they misuse the account** -- yeah. We do that with the *"young adult" students* at the college I work at. While the OP's kids may well be able to take responsibility well (and this would be good training), asking the average student to take responsibility for their own actions works about as well as putting a roof-rack on a helicopter.

Comment: @William my experience is they just get whiny when you do it.

Answer (score 5):

Theoretically, there is no concern. When you buy Minecraft for an account, the system uses the credit card's info to charge the $27 you spend for the game to your card, and doesn't ever use it again. The only thing a Minecraft password can be used for is to change the player's skin by signing on to Minecraft.net, and logging in on the Minecraft Launcher in order to play.

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, the worst they can do is lose the account; however there are a number of phishing scams out there specific to Minecraft.  Make sure you educate your kids about what websites they should log into with their Minecraft account and who they should give the password to.  The answers being simply, Minecraft*.net*, Mojang.com, and no one and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any problem. You should only clean up your browser history, so that they can't see the credit card details. The credit card details aren't stored, so I think it is even better if you told them the password (and the email as well). You should also let them change it, so that they can remember it better (they may not remember the password you used)

EDIT: I just remembered: tell them that they should **never** log in into any other "things" using their account either than:

- Minecraft.net
- Mojang.com
- The minecraft launcher

There are also some other launchers that don't offer any risk of logging into them with their account if downloaded from the right place.

- FTB Launcher
- ATLauncher
- Techinc Launcher

All of those are safe. Here are some websites that **are not** safe:

- Websites offering capes
- Websites offering free gift codes
- Cracked launchers. Even though some of them are safe (some only request the username) others also require you to insert a fake password. I won't recommend you to put there your **real** password, because you might loose your account.

PS - Also tell them to don't tell the password (and not only the minecraft password, all of them) to their friends!